# How to get all the meanings when I use Google translate API

Tags: google-translate

I used the Google API to translate word from Ar to En I want to translate only one word every time and I want to get all the possible meaning for that word not only one meaning. How can I do that, all the codes I found give only one translation.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately it is impossible for the current version of Google Translate API (v.2).

From the FAQ (https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/faq):

> Q: Is it possible to get multiple translations of a word?
>
> A: No. This feature is only available via the web interface
> at translate.google.com

Comment: How about now? Is there any way to do it now?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a npm package that can do exactly what you want - [extended google translate api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/extended-google-translate-api)

However, this package uses unofficial google translate API, so you can't use it in any commercial projects.